# Updating Ansible version using "sudo pip install ansible --upgrade" does not update the core modules

Tags: pip, centos6, ansible

I used `sudo pip install ansible --upgrade` to upgrade Ansible on CentOS 6.  When I typed `ansible --version`, it gave me the updated version number.  However all the Ansible core modules did not get updated.  I had to manually update the core modules one by one from the source.

Does anyone know how to do Ansible version update with all the core modules being updated as well?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has something todo with Ansible recently (I think around `1.7.x`) being split up from one github repo into 3 separate github repos. Ansible core and Ansible modules not in the same repository any longer.

How did you install Ansible in the first place? Did you use `pip install <ansible-repo>`? Then that might be the problem. The [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-pip) say to use `easy_install` with pip. If you did that, maybe still just `pip uninstall` it and re-install.

Also, there is a `rpm` to use with `yum` on CentOS. (which I use and did not have problems updating)